# ValueError: The truth value of a GeoDataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, python-3.x, geopandas

I have DataFrame and I want to do, what seems to be an easy step

```
import pandas as pd

# initialize list of lists
data = [['tom', 10], ['nick', 15], ['juli', 14]]
  
# Create the pandas DataFrame
mydf = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Age'])

f = mydf  

if(f == mydf or f == clinic):
    
    print("yes it is ok ")
else:
    print("no its not ok ")
```

Why am I getting the following error for this little program?

ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: `x == a | b | c` does not do what you think it does (it tries to do a boolean-or of `a`, `b` and `c` and compares the result to `x`). You need `x == a | x == b | x == c`. Or maybe `x in [a, b, c]`

Comment: good point, i will edit this, but the main problem still stands

Comment: Does it thought? I think the problems is *caused* by trying to interpret `doctors` in a boolean context.

Comment: Please show a [mre] (i.e., add a definition for `doctors`, `clinic`, `hospital`, etc. which we can use to get the same error, and/or reduce the amount of definitions needed to reproduce the problem).

Comment: That's not *minimal*. We shouldn't need to install `geopandas` or `osmnx` to get this error.

Comment: any chance the problem is simply using `|` instead of `or`?

Comment: Thank you for the comment mkrieger1. I tried to give a better minimal rep example

Comment: @SillyFreak   `|` instead of `or` gets me the following error TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'str' and 'str'

Comment: @Peter I meant that the *problem* is `|`, which you're using in your original code, and wanted to ask you to try out `or`. In any case, it seems that in the code you posted as a solution, the material difference is that you replaced `==` with `is`, which [compares objects by identity](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is not the best solution, but an ok alternative for this problem:

```
# Get the name of a DataFrame 
def get_df_name(df):
    name =[x for x in globals() if globals()[x] is df][0]
    return name
```

```
f = doctors  ##  GeoDataFrame
f = get_df_name(f)

if(f == "doctors" or f == "clinic"):
    
    print("yes it is ok ")
else:
    print("no its not ok ")
```

Output: yes it is ok

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell you why, but comparing two dataframes with `==` seems to trigger this error. You have found a roundabout way of preventing this, `if globals()[x] is df` is the critical part - [the `is` in particular](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons).

Without changing all the logic, it should be sufficient to make this change:

```py
import pandas as pd

# initialize list of lists
data = [['tom', 10], ['nick', 15], ['juli', 14]]
  
# Create the pandas DataFrame
mydf = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Age'])

f = mydf  

if(f is mydf or f is clinic):
    
    print("yes it is ok ")
else:
    print("no its not ok ")
```

However that's only a band-aid solution; consider this modification:

```py
import pandas as pd

# initialize list of lists
data = [['tom', 10], ['nick', 15], ['juli', 14]]
  
# Create the pandas DataFrame
mydf = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Age'])
mydf2 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Age'])  # a separate but equal dataframe

f = mydf2  

if(f is mydf or f is clinic):
    
    print("yes it is ok ")
else:
    print("no its not ok ")  # output: not its not ok
```

The real solution would be to use [`pandas.DataFrame.equals`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.equals.html):

```py
import pandas as pd

# initialize list of lists
data = [['tom', 10], ['nick', 15], ['juli', 14]]
  
# Create the pandas DataFrame
mydf = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Age'])
mydf2 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Age'])

f = mydf2  

if(f.equals(mydf) or f.equals(clinic)):
    
    print("yes it is ok ")  # output: yes it is ok
else:
    print("no its not ok ")
```